# Trouble with layout on various screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

My screen layout has elements placed correctly

[image]

but when I switch to another screen, eg. iphone 7 plus

[image: iPhone7+]

or se

[image: iPhoneSE]

things change. I've set constrains, height and witdh when I suppose I should, but apparently it does not want to cooperate with me. Please tell me what constrains and heights, widths should I set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below constraint

1. For the red and green View You need to give Equal Width Constraint.
2. For Blue View at the center you need to give Center Horizontally Constraint.
3. For the bar at the bottom You need to give Bottom distance from the Red/Green Top Constraint.